# AngularJS Best way to retrigger controller on View Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-ng-change

So using an angularJS webapp and I am plotting some graphs using nvd3.

I have a factory which is pulling the data from an API and a controller which gets the data from the factory, do some calculations and plot the graph. 
Let's say I have a dropdown list in my view with different parameters options for the REST API call, and each one of them is going to produce a different graph.

what is the best way of, when the user chooses an option from the dropdown list, to repeat the calculations in controller and replot the new graph.

I tried using the `ng-change=callAnUpdateFunction(foo)` but I wasn't successful on retriggering the controller.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5f4kp17z/)!

Thanks

Comment: post something u have tried ? :)

Comment: Would you mind to set up a simple example on plunker? Also, was there any error thrown?

Comment: are you using ngRoute or uiRouter?? answer differs on basis of routing you are using..

Comment: @Sprottenwels I added an example on jsfiddle. No error is thrown.

Comment: @HarishR I am using ngRoute. Thanks .

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha Take a look at my updated post.

Comment: fiddle is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following approach:
Use $watch to observe your select from dropdown, something like:

```
$scope.$watch('valueBindToSelect', function(){
   $scope.$emit('SelectValueChangedEvent');
});

$scope.$on('SelectValueChangedEvent', function(){
  doSomeComputationAndReplotGraph();
})
```

Comment: What's bad about using the `ngChange` directive? I'd say that avoiding $watch is a good thing.

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/

http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Comment: I prefer to use $watch if (1) there are no more than 100 of them (2) I am not sure whether the change comes only from user manually selecting from the dropdown.

Comment: @ABOS I am trying to apply your code in my codebase. So let's assume that I want the retriggering to happen when the $scope.name changes. In this situation what is valueBindToSelect and SelectValueChangedEvent. Thanks